# Ввод с клавиатуры изменить на ввод из файла

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть код, в котором данные вводятся с клавиатуры. Как изменить код, чтобы данные вводились из файла?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    public static void PrintValues(IEnumerable myCollection)
    {
        foreach (Object obj in myCollection)
            Console.Write("{0}", obj);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Object qwer2;
        Stack stk = new Stack();
        string term, qwer1, a1, a2, a3;
        Console.WriteLine("Write term in OPN: ");
        term = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] split = term.Split(new Char[] { ' ' });
        foreach (string s in split)
        {
            if (s.Trim() != "")
            {
                Regex rgx = new Regex("[A-Za-z0-9]");
                foreach (char str in s)
                    if (rgx.IsMatch(s))
                        stk.Push(s);

                    else
                    {
                        if (s == "+" || s == "-")
                        {
                            qwer2 = stk.Pop();
                            a3 = qwer2.ToString();
                            a2 = s.ToString();
                            qwer2 = stk.Pop();
                            a1 = qwer2.ToString();
                            qwer1 = string.Concat("(" + a1 + a2 + a3 + ")");
                            stk.Push(qwer1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            qwer2 = stk.Pop();
                            a3 = qwer2.ToString();
                            a2 = s.ToString();
                            qwer2 = stk.Pop();
                            a1 = qwer2.ToString();
                            qwer1 = string.Concat(a1 + a2 + a3);
                            stk.Push(qwer1);
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        PrintValues(stk);
    }
}
```

Comment: весь необходимый код должен быть вставлен непосредственно в вопрос, ссылка может быть только дополнением

Answer (score 2):

Поменяйте `Console.ReadLine` на `StreamReader.ReadLine`. В [документации](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) есть пример. И [ещё один](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287535.aspx).

---

В вашем случае точка ввода одна, значит, вместо

```
term = Console.ReadLine();
```

надо написать

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(path_to_your_file)) 
    term = sr.ReadLine();
```

Comment: А можно поконкретнее на моем примере? А то я запутался совсем.

Comment: @alex77: Ну вы уж совсем хотите, чтобы разжевали. Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы мне очень помогли.  Еще вопрос. Чтобы программа посчитала значение выводимого выражения, необходимо вставлять код для программы "Калькулятор"?